# How to use member as object of other class?

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to create member variable `sptr` of `ABC` which is object of other class `SmartPointer`. And then assign value to that member variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class SmartPointer
{
    private:
        int *ptr;

    public:
        SmartPointer(int *p);
        int& operator *();
        ~SmartPointer();
};

SmartPointer::SmartPointer(int *p = NULL)
{
    cout<<"Initilaize SmartPointer"<<p<< endl;
    ptr = p;
}

int& SmartPointer:: operator *()
{  
    return *ptr; 
}


SmartPointer::~SmartPointer()
{

    cout<<"De-Initilaize SmartPointer"<<endl;
    delete ptr;
}


class ABC
{
    private:
        int a;
        SmartPointer *sptr;
        int ref;
    public:
        ABC();                           // Simple constructor.
        ABC(int a, int b);               // Parameterized constructor.
     //     ABC(const ABC &obj);             // Copy constructor.
        ~ABC();                          // Destructor.
        void display();                  // Display.
    //  ABC& operator=(const ABC &obj);  // Operator Overload.
};


ABC::ABC() 
{
    ref= 1;
}


ABC::ABC(int a, int b) 
{
    cout << "Parameterized constructor input" << endl;
    // allocate memory for the pointer;
    sptr = new SmartPointer(&a);
    cout << "Parameterized constructor Out"<<sptr << endl;
}

ABC::~ABC(void) 
{
    cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
    ref --;
    if(ref==0)
    {  
        //delete sptr;
    }
}


void ABC::display() 
{

}


int main()
{
//  int a = 10;
//  SmartPointer obj1(&a);

    // Normal.
    ABC obj2(1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

created `sptr = new SmartPointer(&a);`, but how to get value of `sptr` ?

Comment: Dereference the pointer? How did you get this far without knowing how to dereference a pointer? I mean, you wrote a function for it: `int& operator *();`

EDIT: I should say you copy-pasted the definition for SmartPointer from elsewhere, because you clearly don't understand how to use it. `SmartPointer` will eventually call `delete` on the passed-in pointer, and you're going to get a segfault because `a` is on the stack, not the heap.

Comment: I am going to add `ref` variable in `SmartPointer` which will count how many objects of `ABC` are using same `SmartPointer` object. If `ref` is `1` then delete `ptr` from destructor of `SmartPointer` otherwise just decrement `ref` value. but I am not able to get how to assign and get values.

Comment: That "smart" member doesn't seem to have any advantages over a plain `int*`. What is the point of using that class there?

Comment: If you want a reference counted pointer, use `std::shared_ptr`. If you want your own reference counted pointer, it'd be a good idea to study std::shared_ptr first. Hint: std::shared_ptr doesn't keep the counter *in* the pointer. There may be many pointers that point to the same object, they all need to use the same counter.

Comment: TBH, I think you should still be working on the basics. "create member variable sptr which is object of other class SmartPointer" and then you write `SmartPointer *sptr;`. No, that's not a member of type `SmartPointer`. That is a dumb pointer to a `SmartPointer`.

Comment: Do you really want a **pointer to a `SmartPointer`**, or did you want a `SmartPointer` instance?  Remember, in C++ you don't need to use `new` for every variable.